# How to keep current page number active when i click Go Back in my other component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, local-storage

How to keep current page number active when i click Go Back in my other component in React JS.
I have Three components first is Design Component, second is Pagination Component and third is Item Details component. When i click on data coming from API , it uses ID and take me to the ItemDetails component of that specific ID. In ItemDetails component, i created a button which is 'Go Back'. **I want to come back on my current page where i clicked the ID but when i click on Go Back button it takes me to the first Page.**

Here is my Design Component where i want to use localStorage concept but how to use it?, i don't know.

```
    // /* eslint-disable react/prop-types */ // TODO: upgrade to latest eslint tooling
import "../src/App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import Pagination from "./Pagination";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

let PageSize = 2;

export default function Design() {
  const [search, setSearchTerm] = useState("all");
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
  const data = window.localStorage.getItem('pnum');
  console.log(`data is: ${data}`)
  if(data !== null) setCurrentPage(JSON.parse(data))
},[])

useEffect(() => {
window.localStorage.setItem('pnum', JSON.stringify(currentPage))
},[currentPage])

  const currentTableData = useMemo(() => {
    const firstPageIndex = (currentPage - 1) * PageSize;
    const lastPageIndex = firstPageIndex + PageSize;
    return records.slice(firstPageIndex, lastPageIndex);
  }, [currentPage, records]);

  useEffect(() => {
    searchRecords();
  }, []);

  const searchRecords = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://fruityvice.com/api/fruit/${search}`);
      setRecords(search === "all" ? res.data : [res.data]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error searching record:", error);
      setRecords([]);
    }
  };

  const fetchSuggestions = async (input) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all`);
      const fruits = res.data.map((fruit) => fruit.name);
      const filteredSuggestions = fruits.filter((fruit) =>
        fruit.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
      );
      setSuggestions(filteredSuggestions);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching suggestions:", error);
      setSuggestions([]);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    setSearchTerm(inputValue);
    fetchSuggestions(inputValue);
  };

  const getTotalNutritions = (item) => {
    return Object.values(item.nutritions).reduce(
      (total, value) => total + Math.trunc(value),
      0
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="main--heading">Fruit Project</h1>
      <div className="main">
        <input
          className="input"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          list="suggestions"
          placeholder="Search Fruit"
        />
        <datalist id="suggestions">
          {suggestions.map((fruit, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={fruit} />
          ))}
        </datalist>
        <button className="btn" onClick={searchRecords}>
          Search Fruit
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Sr No</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Family</th>
              <th>Order</th>
              <th>Nutritions</th>
              <th>Genus</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {Array.isArray(currentTableData) && currentTableData.length > 0 ? (
              currentTableData
                .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
                .map((item) => (
                  <tr key={item.id}>
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                    {/* <td>{item.name}</td> */}
                    <td>
                <Link to={`/details/${item.id}`}>View Details</Link>
                    </td>
                    <td>{item.family}</td>
                    <td>{item.order}</td>
                    <td>{getTotalNutritions(item)}</td>
                    <td>{item.genus}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))
            ) : (
              <tr>
                <td>No data available</td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <Pagination
          className="pagination-bar"
          currentPage={currentPage}
          totalCount={records.length}
          pageSize={PageSize}
          onPageChange={(page) => {setCurrentPage(page)}
          }
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

and my itemDetails component is :

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ItemDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();   

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Item Details</h2>
      <p>{`${id}:I am stuck there.`}</p>
      <Link  to={`/`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Go Back</Link>

    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

might be easier to give a meaningful answer if you can provide some minimal reproduction of the issue and link it but we can give it a try.

There are many design decisions as to how to structure your code to accomplish this, it's up to you and your requirements what to chose. Right now your local storage solution is okay but unless there was some other reason to persist it there I personally would not go for that. You could keep it in state higher in the tree or as url param if appropriate but I'll try and give more detail about that after.

To be honest I'm not so sure without access to the code why the effects for persisting page number are not working. If I recall correctly in react the hooks should run in the order they are declared, I'm not sure its a guarantee. But even if it is I think it's not the most robust design.

Here are some alternatives, I wont go in full depth because there's a lot of variations possible and lots of documentation for all the things, so I'll just briefly explain the possible approaches, if you would like some more detail on a specific one I can edit.

**State** you can keep the page as state so long as the state is common to all the routes for which you would like it to persist. This implies that the details page should be rendered as a child of the Design component. The most extreme example would be storing the page number as app state, in this context with react router this means on the component that defines the routes or higher in the tree. Then it could be exposed with context or even passed as props although that's not very practical. Context also seems not very practical. So ideally you would set it up so that details page is rendered as a descendant of Design. There are many approaches, it could be a dialog/modal, it could be some nested routing with outlet, for react router you can look up the many approaches.

**URL param** You could also set the page number as an optional url parameter that gets updated in a similar way to local storage, then when you navigate back it will be the same page, and you can update the link to use history back or similar, you could even look at the previous entry in history and explicitly set that as the href. This also has the advantage that the page could be shared etc.. if someone shares a link they will go to same pagination which is convenient for user.

To sum it up, I think these two approaches are not bad and you can even combine them. I think if you look into sharing state between routes and also url parameters you'll be in a good spot for what you're trying to achieve.

**Example for keeping state higher up in the tree**
Here's an example with some explanation, this uses React Router components and just passes the props.

First we import everything we need

import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

```
import {
  useParams,
  Routes,
  Route,
  BrowserRouter,
  Link,
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

We then declare any types and some mock data for the example and a simple component that renders the item. Just renders the id and a link back to `/`

```
type Item = {
  readonly id: number;
};

const MOCK_DATA: readonly Item[] = Array.from({ length: 25 }, (...[, i]) => ({
  id: i,
}));

const Detail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      id={id}
      <Link to="/">Back</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now is the important part actually relevant to the problem we are trying to solve.

```
type ListProps = {
  readonly data: readonly Item[];
  readonly page: number;
  readonly onChangePage: (deltaPage: number) => void;
};

const itemsPerPage = 5;

const List = (props: ListProps) => {
  const dataIndex0 = (props.page - 1) * itemsPerPage;
  const pageData = props.data.slice(dataIndex0, dataIndex0 + itemsPerPage);
  return (
    <div>
      LIST OF DATA
      <ol>
        {pageData.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id} style={{ listStyle: 'none' }}>
            <span> {item.id} </span>
            <Link to={`/details/${item.id}`}> details </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
      <span>page:{props.page}</span>
      <button onClick={() => props.onChangePage(-1)}>pre</button>
      <button onClick={() => props.onChangePage(1)}>next</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here we set up a basic list component, this would be equivalent to the `Design` component in your example. The important parts to note are that page state is not stored in this component, it is passed to it by a parent, here you could use context instead if you want.

Then the App

```
const App = () => {
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <List
              data={MOCK_DATA}
              page={pageNumber}
              onChangePage={(delta) => setPageNumber((x) => x + delta)}
            />
          }
        />
        <Route path="/details/:id" element={<Detail />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Here the page state is declared in the App. App is a common parent to both the Details and List component, this means that navigation between these component will not reset the state.

We have route `/` which will render the List, we pass it page number and a function that accepts the difference in pages to update page, you can change this to however you need but the important part is to have some method of getting and setting page number from List.

Here's a link to the playground https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9xkbua?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: Thank You Max, but i am new and my understanding of english language is intermediate etc. Can you write a code for me which i try there?

Comment: Hi yea I added a simple example to show how it can work to keep state higher up in the tree. The state does not have to be on App, the important part is that it needs to be somewhere common to both the details and list.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value from the local storage when you are setting the initial value to the state.

```
const pnum = window.localStorage.getItem('pnum', JSON.stringify(currentPage));
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(pnum ?? 1);
```